# Resize View in WindowManager in android

Tags: android, resize, ontouch

I would like to re-size my view which is created using service in Windowmanager on touch I have changed height and width it is working properly.

But I have found that **params.x** and **params.y** is not changing so it is moving at the time of resizing the view.

And for that I found this values for different situation

- when view is **small**
  and at **top left** params.x = -310 params.y = -826
- when view is **small** and at **bottom left** params.x = -364 params.y = 958
- when view is **big** and at **top left** params.x = -253 params.y = -657
- when view is **big** and at **bottom left** params.x = -323 params.y = 888

  and this is my code of ontouch

  ```
                      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                          initialX = params.width;
                          initialY = params.height;
                          initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                          initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                          Log.w("DOWN","X="+params.x+" Y="+params.y);
                          return true;

                      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                          params.width = (int) (initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX));
                          params.height = (int) (initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY));
                          Log.w("MOVE","X="+params.x+" Y="+params.y);
                          windowManager.updateViewLayout(videoLoder, params);
                          return true;
  ```
- How to get params.x and params.y as change in the height and width ?
- And how this params.x and params.y is calculated?

I have found the some sort of [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829800/android-resize-view-in-windowmanager) but answered yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have set **gravity** to center so this issue was raised but after seting gravity to top left all working like charm

```
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
```

Might be helpful to some one